# tensorflow save and restore autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used tf.layers.dense to build a fully connected autoencoder. and I want to save it and restore only the encoder to get the embedding output.

How to use tf.train.saver to restore only the encoder? Because I want to set different batch size of the restored model, to input only one data into it.

I saw many tutorials but there is no tutorials about this.

Is there any standard solution about this

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about memory space the easiest way is by saving the whole graph (encoder and decoder) and when using it for prediction, you can pass the last layer of the encoder as the fetch argument. Tensorflow will only calculate to this point and you don't have any computational difference compared to only saving the encoder.

Otherwise you can create two graphs (one for the encoder, one for the decoder) an train them at the same time and train them together. But this is I bit more complex.

Comment: Thank you, and how to make the batch_size different when restoring the model?

Comment: Formally this is a new question, but it is very simple so: Set the first index of the input shape as -1. E.g. a gray picture with 30x30 pixels has the shape of [-1, 30, 30, 1].  Tensorflow will then automatically calculat the batch size. And please mark my answer as answered if it fixed your problem.